# "Illegal characters in path" error opening service config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, config, illegal-characters

I am trying to read a section of a Windows service configuration file and extract a value (port number). Following code works fine on my local machine but not in any server I tested even though the service is installed in exact same folder structure.

On servers, I get "illegal character in path" error (I added a couple of try-catch to see where it dies and what the message was).

```
public static string GetCurrentTCPPort()
{
    string sTCPPort = "7899";
    string ServiceName = "IDC - Tcp Interface Service";
    using (ManagementObject wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + ServiceName + "'"))
    {
        try
        {
            wmiService.Get();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Died in GetCurrentTCPPort - wmiService.Get()");
        }
        string ServiceExePath = wmiService["PathName"].ToString();
        System.Configuration.Configuration config;

        try
        {
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ServiceExePath); // FilePath = "C:\\IDC\\APP\\IDC - Tcp Interface Service\\IDC.Service.TcpInterface.exe.config"
            string[] saLiteningIPs = config.AppSettings.Settings["TcpServerListenIpAddrsAndPortNos"].Value.Split(',');    // "1.2.3.4:7899,1.2.3.5:7899"

            if (saLiteningIPs.Length > 0)
            {
                sTCPPort = saLiteningIPs[0].Split(':')[1];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  // This exception is thrown

            string sExcep = string.Format("Died in GetCurrentTCPPort - OpenExeConfiguration(); ServiceExePath: {0}{1}Exception: {2}", ServiceExePath, Environment.NewLine, ex.Message);
            throw new Exception(sExcep);
        }
    }
    return sTCPPort;  
}
```

When I run it, I get:

```
Died in GetCurrentTCPPort - OpenExeConfiguration(); currentserviceExePath: "C:\IDC\APP\IDC - Tcp Interface Service\IDC.Service.TcpInterface.exe"
Exception: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Illegal characters in path.
```

Screen shot of config file location:
[image: Config file location]

**Update - With the fix**

```
public static string GetCurrentTCPPort()
{
    string sTCPPort = "7899";
    string ServiceName = "IDC - Tcp Interface Service";
    using (ManagementObject wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + ServiceName + "'"))
    {
        try
        {
            wmiService.Get();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Died in GetCurrentTCPPort - wmiService.Get()");
        }
        string ServiceExePath = wmiService["PathName"].ToString();

        // Added below two lines to fix the issue
        List<char> invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars().ToList();
        invalidPathChars.ForEach(c => ServiceExePath = ServiceExePath.Replace(c.ToString(), String.Empty));

        System.Configuration.Configuration config;

        try
        {
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ServiceExePath);
            string[] saLiteningIPs = config.AppSettings.Settings["TcpServerListenIpAddrsAndPortNos"].Value.Split(',');

            if (saLiteningIPs.Length > 0)
            {
                sTCPPort = saLiteningIPs[0].Split(':')[1];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  // This exception is thrown

            string sExcep = string.Format("Died in GetCurrentTCPPort - OpenExeConfiguration(); ServiceExePath: {0}{1}Exception: {2}", ServiceExePath, Environment.NewLine, ex.Message);
            throw new Exception(sExcep);
        }
    }
    return sTCPPort;  
}
```

Comment: Without more information on the environments it fails on it's hard to say for sure, but I would bet the "illegal character" is the spaces

Comment: But I have this service installed locally in exactly same folder, with space in it, and it works fine. I would have thought the same had it not worked locally.

Comment: Please open a command prompt in that folder and do a `dir` such that we can see the folder and filename. Include a screenshot of it in your question.

Comment: Also please type in `?config` in to the `Immediate Window` and share its value. Also `config.Length`.

Comment: @mjwills added screenshot, but typing ?config in immediate window shows "The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode. " or if app is not running "The expression cannot be evaluated while in design mode."

Comment: You need to put that into `Immediate Window` when the debugger is on the line _after_ when `config` was set.

Comment: This wouldn't help. As I said in the post it works fine on my local machine but not on the server. We can't have VS installed on the server so probably the output of immediate windows won't be of much help. Everything looks good when I check the output on my local machine. It doesn't choke and value of FilePath is "FilePath: "C:\\IDC\\APP\\IDC - Tcp Interface Service\\IDC.Service.TcpInterface.exe.config". This is same path as when exception is hit on the server and error is displayed. No complaining about illegal character locally.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this happens when application is deployed to server and not when I run it locally, even though folder structure and files are exactly same on both; maybe there are invisible characters that are caught on the server but not locally.

Nonetheless, it seems the following modification fixed the issue, in case anyone else runs into this problem.

Right below the line getting the exe path, added these two lines:

```
string ServiceExePath = wmiService["PathName"].ToString();
List<char> invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars().ToList();
invalidPathChars.ForEach(c => ServiceExePath = ServiceExePath.Replace(c.ToString(), String.Empty));
```

I have also updated the the question.